# Websphere Liberty - JSP custom tag not working

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, websphere-liberty

I have developed a Spring MVC application and it works fine on Glassfish and Jetty. Now I need to deploy the application on Websphere Liberty version 8.5.5.7. It largely works well, but some pages fail to load with the following exception (see below).

Common for these pages is that they use a custom tag that generates a template page.An example of such a page is this:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>

<t:genericadminpage>
    <jsp:body>
    </jsp:body>
</t:genericadminpage>
```

In an attempt to fix the issue I switched the scope of the included JSTL libraries in the `pom.xml` to `provided`, which solved the issue for some of the pages, but introduced it to others.

Hopefully someone has an inkling of what is going on here and can shed some light on it. If you need more information, please ask.

Thank you in advance.

The exception shown is this:

```
[9/30/15 15:42:21:975 IST] 00000165 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.util.ApplicationErrorUtils           E SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest:978'
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ws.jsp.tagfile.webinf._genericpage incompatible with com.ibm.ws.jsp.tagfile.webinf._genericpage
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1287)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:778)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:475)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:146)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:93)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.jaspi.JaspiServletFilter.doFilter(JaspiServletFilter.java:57)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:1020)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1142)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:81)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:341)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:470)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:404)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:284)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:174)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1157)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:627)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:798)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ws.jsp.tagfile.webinf._genericpage incompatible with com.ibm.ws.jsp.tagfile.webinf._genericpage
    at com.ibm._jsp._home._jspx_meth_t_genericpage_0(_home.java:261)
    at com.ibm._jsp._home._jspService(_home.java:112)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:101)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1287)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:778)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:475)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:119)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:217)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:146)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:93)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.jaspi.JaspiServletFilter.doFilter(JaspiServletFilter.java:57)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:1020)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1142)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1378)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:186)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    ... 62 more
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to use the jstl libraries that are shipped in WebSphere Application Server then I would recommend removing the jstl.jar and standard.jar files from your application.  Based on the exception it seems the runtime is getting confused with the generated tag class file.  This could potentially be caused by two different jstl jars on the classpath.  I would also clear out any previously compiled tag class files that were generated to ensure new ones are created with the jar files removed.

If that does not solve your issue then could you please provide some more detail on the contents of your custom tag.
Regards,
Jay